# Why Tomcat process uses so many ports?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

```sh
~$ sudo netstat -utlpn | grep 2155
tcp6       0      0 :::42851            :::*       LISTEN      2155/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::58212            :::*       LISTEN      2155/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::9092             :::*       LISTEN      2155/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::47556            :::*       LISTEN      2155/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005      :::*       LISTEN      2155/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8999             :::*       LISTEN      2155/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::45131            :::*       LISTEN      2155/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8080             :::*       LISTEN      2155/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::47998            :::*       LISTEN      2155/java
```

where 2155 is the PID of Tomcat process.

Port 8080 is set in Connector in the "server.xml" file. I know that port 8005 is used to shutdown Tomcat. I set JMX to listen on port 8999. I don't know why Tomcat uses other ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They could be JMX connections. JMX uses a fixed port and a random port. I'm not sure if a new client gets a new port. See how mports are open before any JMX connections are made compared with after a JMX connection is made.

Another possibility is clustering. If you enable clustering that will cause a few more sockets to be opened.

Anything else is application generated. Try disabling applications to see which trigger ports to open.

Comment: You are right. I removed all my applications and disabled JMX and tomcat usues only 8005 and 8080 ports. Thanks.